# Linux kernel driver same device on different buses?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there an example of same device using different buses, for example spi and i2c (simultaneously, depending on the choice)?

I am interested in a device that have some common routines, but uses different read/write functions.

For example an adc that has common function for calibration or triggering (never seen this in kernel adc drivers, but why not?), but different functions to read samples from different sources.

How such driver can be realized?
Should i do something like this in my module? :

```
static struct i2c_driver my_i2c_driver = {
         .driver = {
                 .name = "my-i2c-driver",
         },
         .probe = my_i2c_driver_probe,
         .remove = my_i2c_driver_remove,
};

static struct spi_driver my_spi_driver = {
         .driver = {
                 .name   = "my-spi-driver",
         },
         .probe = my_spi_driver_probe,
         .remove = my_spi_driver_remove,         
};

etc... for read/write, ops
```

I'm interested in theory, even if the "no need", "no one does that."

Comment: Such drivers typcially use regmap.

Comment: 2CL thanks, and if not i2c, spi then what?

Comment: Your driver would call either `regmap_init_i2c` or `regmap_init_spi`, depending on the probe routine, and then use the common regmap access functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in 3.10.25 kernel there is such an example,

A ST magnetometer LIS3MDL wich has indeed two interface i2c/spi, controlled via gpio input.

With drivers included in kernel official tree, located in drivers/iio/magnetometer.

With 2 separate driver modules located in st_magn_i2c.c and st_magn_spi.c

st_magn_i2c.c:

```
static struct spi_driver st_magn_driver = {
        .driver = {
                .owner = THIS_MODULE,
                .name = "st-magn-spi",
        },
        .probe = st_magn_spi_probe,
        .remove = st_magn_spi_remove,
        .id_table = st_magn_id_table,
};
```

st_magn_spi.c:

```
static struct i2c_driver st_magn_driver = {
        .driver = {
                .owner = THIS_MODULE,
                .name = "st-magn-i2c",
        },
        .probe = st_magn_i2c_probe,
        .remove = st_magn_i2c_remove,
        .id_table = st_magn_id_table,
};
```

Such devices some times happens - for example PCA2129T RTC.

So in assume this is an example i was almost looking for, though i wanted something more trickier (like a USB and something else) or some basic lead.

Comment: Bosch Magnetometer BMM150 is another example that supports both I2C and SPI.